# Is the communication between memory controller and RAM serial?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-gates, memory, ram

I used to think that the communication between memory controller and RAM is parallel since we know that a RAM stick has multiple pins, just like this:

[image]

But then, from Wikipedia article on [memory controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_controller#Purpose) I found this:

> Reading and writing to DRAM is performed by selecting the row and
> column data addresses of the DRAM as the inputs to the multiplexer
> circuit, where the demultiplexer on the DRAM uses the converted inputs
> to select the correct memory location and return the data, which is
> then passed back through a multiplexer to consolidate the data in
> order to reduce the required bus width for the operation.

I also found this video from Youtube explaining memory controller and at [01:16](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXLY7mrHIaI&t=76s) it shows this:

[image]

Does this mean the communication between memory controller and RAM is serial? If yes, why? To save wires?

And also, where is the demultplexer physically located? Is it in the motherboard or inside the RAM circuit board?

Comment: They are parallel, that's why so many pins.

Comment: @user253751 so the video is incorrect?

Comment: It is more or less correct, but as your first quote explains the multiplexer is inside the RAM chips, so the memory bus isn't even really drawn in the second picture.

Comment: The multiplexer (which is inside the memory controller) time-multiplexes many address signals onto fewer address lines. *Row* address and *Column* address are sent, one after the other, from the memory controller to the RAM, where they are demultiplexed (along with the bank-select bits) to address a particular location in RAM. But these address lines are still very much a parallel bus.

Comment: @brhans usually how many wires are used between the memory controller and the RAM stick? Let's say the system is 64-bit, is 64 wires used?

Answer (score 2):

Communication between memory controller and RAM is through Bus. On a simple level, Bus consist of different types of signals such as data(16-bits, 32-bits, 64-bits, etc.), address(4-bit, 8bit, 16-bit, etc.), clock, read, write and etc.

Now about the multiplexer, it is just a top level rough diagram to understand how RAM work. You see RAM is a set of registers stacked up with address assigned to every location and every location is accessed with multiplexer. So when you have to access a single memory location, than you need a multiplexer to get there.
Now these are not your normal multiplexers, these are multidimensional multiplexers mostly 2D. Typically RAM is made as a 2D grid, one of them selects the row from the grid, and one of them selects the column.

Now when you read a location on the RAM, content of a single registers are sent parallel on the RAM interface but when you read data from multiple locations, then data is sent serially (one register at a time). Now this is just a simple understanding, going deeper into the RAM, it gets a lot complicated and then it is a discussion about the architecture of the RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Access to RAM in modern high-performance systems is quite a bit more complicated than pictured by your sources. In most aspects yes, the communication between memory controller and RAM is serial, mostly because the memory is accessed in chunks called "cachelines", for performance reasons. By itself this access is sequential, a CPU reads multiple sequential locations at a time.

Instead of relying on populist sources like Wiki or layman general-purpose lectures, I would advise to take a look at original sources. To start, all PC DIMMs are made of an array of specialized DDR memory IC, and for example, Micron is a prominent suppler of them. Take a look at one chip (of several similar) that constitute a DIMM module, like [this one](https://media-www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/dram/ddr3/2gb_ddr3_sdram.pdf), at one of its timing diagram:
[image]
The chip must first receive a couple of control signals that form a "command" from memory controller. Then the controller begins to retrieve data (or write) by manipulating various strobes. Take time to skim through the datasheet to get a sense of the topic complexity. I hope these pictures will resolve your controversy.

To add, I am afraid to mention a lot of other aspects that memory controller performs on DIMMS, like timing calibration and individual data channel training.